# Cannot run program "/../../python.exe" (in directory "/PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.8_3.8.240.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0"):Access is denied

Tags: python, django, pycharm

I'm getting this error anytime when creating a new project in pycharm:

> Cannot run program "C:\Program
>   Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.8_3.8.240.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\python.exe"
>   (in directory "C:\Program
>   Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.8_3.8.240.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0"):
>   CreateProcess error=5, Access is denied

I have Python 3.8 installed from Windows Store but when I try to create the project it says "Choose another SDK"

It seems like a fairly common issue but since I'm new to Python I'm not really sure what it involves.

Answer (score 0):

Try installing Python 3 from the actual Python Webpage.

The windows store version may be confusing pycharm by storing/sorting the .py files in an odd way. Could also be a PATH issue due to windows store version etc.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks, will give this a shot and let you know!